# How to display the number of objects in an array as Sprites on screen in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my game I have the number of lives saved in an array, the lives are then displayed in the top right of the game view during gameplay. The way I have it done this is working but I hit problems when moving to the next level.

This works fine in the first level, I can lose lives when hit but I did hit a problem when I tried to have extras life pickups. I was able to add to the array but couldn't display the extra life on the screen. I ended up cutting this feature from the game but now hit the same problem when player advances to next level. Using the same loop will result in the player having three lives again no matter how many are lost in the previous level.

I know the problem is the loop I've used caused I've set the for in loop to be 1 to 3. I'm not great a programming and not sure what kind of loop to use for this and when Googling for a solution I'm obviously not asking the right questions to point me in the right direction.

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    //lives
    static var livesArray:[SKSpriteNode]!
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        //Call Lives method
        addLives()
    }
    
    func addLives() {
            GameScene.livesArray = [SKSpriteNode]()
        
            for life in 1...3 {
                let lifeNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Life")
                lifeNode.position = CGPoint(x: 350 - CGFloat(4 - life) * lifeNode.size.width, y: 525)
                addChild(lifeNode)
                GameScene.livesArray.append(lifeNode)
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Try replacing the 3 with a variable in your for loop.

Comment: When you say variable in for for loop, do you mean my 'lifeNode' variable

Comment: Not your lifeNode variable. A variable which stores the number of lives your player has. You could also try using a While loop. Look at these example https://codewithchris.com/swift-loops/

Comment: I was trying to add the number of lives to my array already but now thinking about it from viewing your comment I didn't think about creating another variable, sounds so obvious now. My programming skills suck haha. Thanks very much for taking time and posting the link, I'll give this a go.

Comment: No problem. The more you code the easier it gets.